# How to fix freezing mplayer on Mac for music play?

Tags: macos, music, mplayer

I want to play music on a MacBook Air (10.14.6) with `mplayer` on the command line. But sometimes when I load a page in a browser, the music briefly stops, and then continues. Sometimes even for some seconds. This is very annoying. I want to listen to the music continuously (while using a browser!).

I have tried to run the following command:

```
sudo nice -n -20 mplayer -shuffle Music/...
```

Is there anything else I can try?
Maybe there is a better command line tool?

Comment: The OS is responsible for guaranteeing resource bandwidth to processes, but some poorly-written processes can take more than their fair share. Are you using Chrome or Firefox as your browser?

Comment: I use both chrome and firefox

Answer (score 2):

Your browser may be at fault for consuming excessive system resources. Try switching to Safari and don’t run Chrome or Firefox at all for a while and see if the glitches persist or go away.

**UPDATE:**

Since you’ve confirmed that your browser is at fault, here are a few routes we can take.

0. Obvious first step: Make sure you’re on the most recent build of *Firefox* and *mplayer* in case there have been bug fixes or performance enhancements made. You can also try updating to a more recent macOS for similar reasons. (Big Sur is not recommended, though.)
1. We can try to do a deep dive and start doing `DTrace` profiling of *Firefox* and *mplayer*, possibly uncovering bugs in one or the other (or in other parts of the OS).
2. You could try switching to a different music player (e.g., try the default *Music.app* for a bit and see if it’s better-behaved) in case there’s a specific resource contention between browser and *mplayer.*
3. Depending on how much free RAM you have and how big your music library is, you could copy (a part of) your library to a RAM disk and stream from there. This would help if the bottleneck is I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure I can do that (as without a browser I cannot work)

Comment: Safari is a browser :)

Comment: I know that. But I have all the profiles, work profiles, bookmarks, required extensions NOT on safari.

Comment: I would encourage you to treat this as an isolation experiment. It’s an important data point. Do your best to live as long as possible on Safari and notice if you have even a *single* instance of glitching.

Comment: And if that would be the case, what then? I need to work with firefox and chrome wile I like to listen to uninterrupted music?

Comment: Let’s take that one step at a time. First we need to determine whether it is, indeed, the browser. It may not be. If it is, we can think of workarounds and mitigations.

Comment: It is the browser (at least firefox). I was listening to music, and as I opened the firefox browser, the music did stop playing for a second.